# RelativeLayout within ListView

Tags: android

I plan on adding an activity to my app that shows a lot of information in a list view. Is it possible to use RelativeLayouts as ListView elements? I added a picture to show you what I mean.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.

In your list's adapter:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (vi==null) {
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_list_elem, null);
            vholder = new ViewHolder(vi, position);
            vi.setTag(vholder);
        }
        ......
    }
}
```

}

And the list element layout (my_list_elem.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:chd="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.marketingvici.profix"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"   >

    < your staff here >

</RelativeLayout>
```